# How to print only the last match using itertools in python?

Tags: python, python-itertools

I have the following code:

```
p = ['a','b','c','d']
q = ['a','a','x','y','z']

for (p, q) in itertools.product(p, q):
    if p == q:
        print(q)
```

it prints:

```
a
a
```

After adding some additional logs it seems that the first item of `p` is compared with the first item of `q`, then first item of `p` with second item of `q`, first item of `p` with third item of `q` etc.

How can I modify this code so that it will only print the last match? So I only want the output `a` once (because of the comparison of the first item of `p` and the second item in `q` in this case)

Comment: Are you prevented from creating and accumulating values in a list and then converting them to a set?

Comment: What is your code *supposed to do?*

Comment: Are you finding common characters between the two lists?

Comment: I agree with @juanpa.arrivillaga that it makes no sense to give any solutions without knowing your intention.

Comment: `[a for a, b in itertools.product(p, q) if a == b][-1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not simply use a set to find common characters between the two lists

```
p = ['a','b','c','d']
q = ['a','a','x','y','z']

print(set(p).intersection(set(q)))
```

The output will be `{'a'}`

Or if you cannot use a set, collect all matches into a list and print the last element

```
import itertools

p = ['a','b','c','d']
q = ['a','a','x','y','z']

items = []
for (p, q) in itertools.product(p, q):
    #Collect all matches in a list
    if p == q:
        items.append((p,q))

#Print the last item
print(items[-1])
```

The output will be `('a', 'a')`

Comment: Can you use a set with intersection with p (list of strings) and q (list of dicts, and a key of a dict is matching with a string from p).?

Comment: Yes, a set of p and a set of list of keys of the dict @DenCowboy so `set(p)` and `set(dct)`

Comment: I tried: print(set(a).intersection(set(b['value']))) but it returned: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: What is `a` and `b` can you be more clear about this, also this seems unrelated to the question in hand @DenCowboy

Comment: Sorry, I mean like p and q.  p is just like in the original question and q is actually a list of dicts like [{'value': 'a'},{'value': 's'},{'value': 't'}]

Comment: Yes, the second set will be of the list `[item  for v in q for item in v.values()]`,where you collect all values from `q` in a list and make it a set @DenCowboy and you convert this list to a set and compare it to `set(q)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194069/discussion-between-devesh-kumar-singh-and-dencowboy).

Answer (score 1):

If you can't afford to turn `p` and `q` into sets first because they're exorbitantly large, you can add the already matched values to a set as you go and check for inclusion:

```
p = ['a','b','c','d']
q = ['a','a','x','y','z']
seen = set([])

for a, b in itertools.product(p, q):
    if a == b and b not in seen:
        print(b)
        seen.add(b)
```

Answer (score -1):

In order to do so I would simply reverse both `list`s that is:

```
import itertools
p = ['a','b','c','d']
q = ['a','a','x','y','z']

for (x, y) in itertools.product(p[::-1], q[::-1]):
    if x == y:
        print(y)
        break
```

Output:

```
a
```